# How can I make a Border's border dashed?

Tags: wpf

How can I give a `Border` control a dashed border? I also need it to have rounded corners (i.e. `CornerRadius` > 0).

Comment: Look right! There are two the same questions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048137/how-do-i-create-a-dashed-border-with-rounded-corners-in-wpf?rq=1

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195395/how-can-i-achieve-a-dashed-or-dotted-border-in-wpf?rq=1

Comment: Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6196181/632337).

Comment: The question above, that is supposedly a duplicate of my question, doesn't help me. That includes your link Rohit. I've been there already. You guys are a bit too overzealous with that duplicate question stuff. Be more careful, please. Second, I had been searching on this for an hour before I posted and didn't come by the second link. I didn't know rectangles could be rounded. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Border>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="2.0 2.0" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFD267"/>
        <!-- put other contents in here-->
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Can not directly have StrokeDashArray on border, but can get similar effect with the above.

Comment: Since you actually gave me an answer I can work with and didn't give me a speech about duplicating questions, I will select yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a brush like this:

```
<LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute"
                     SpreadMethod="Repeat"
                     StartPoint="0,0.5"
                     EndPoint="4,0.5">
    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                  Color="#40000000" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.5"
                  Color="#40000000" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.501"
                  Color="Transparent" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```