# Create dashed border in avalonia 11

Tags: .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I need to create control theme with dotted border in .net avalonia 11.

In previous versions there was appropriate property BorderDashOffset in border control but it was removed.

Are there any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BorderDashOffset on the border element was unfortunately a preview feature that never made it into the stable release.

The recommended work around is "Any apps needing line dashes will need to fall back to using Shapes directly (as done in WPF/WinUI)."

See: 
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/11548 
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/8380

Based on some research on how WPF does this with shapes I was able to create the code below. (see [Dotted border in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391591/how-can-i-make-a-borders-border-dashed))

```
<Grid Background="#FFD267">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="5, 1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7"  Fill="White"></Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Margin="10">Hello world!</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This should produce the following:

[image: Dashed Border Example]

Comment: This is good approach but I can not apply border CornerRadius with it

Comment: Don't use a border element, I had left it in my last answer to set the background colour. Use the RadiusX & RadiusY to set the corner Radius I have update the answer to make this clear.

Comment: Thank a lot! I missed that Rectangle has RadiusX and RadiusY properties.

Appreciate your help.