# WPF Rectangle StrokeDashArray not printing correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a rectangle drawn as in this post ([How do I create a dashed border with rounded corners in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048137/how-do-i-create-a-dashed-border-with-rounded-corners-in-wpf)).  It looks great on the screen but when I print it, the rectangle reverts to a solid line.

Is there something going on with pixels or post script support for this control?

Comment: how do you print it? by FlowDocument? or what

Comment: @safi It's a DocumentViewer containing a FixedDocument